# as.Date and format differences

Tags: r, date

I am converting dates formatted as "Mar.01" and I thought it would be straightforward to cast using standard formatting rules, but I have an issue with it.

For example, if I produce a date like so:

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%b%y")
[1] "May13"
```

I cannot convert it back to a date object using the same pattern::

```
as.Date(format(Sys.Date(), "%b%y"),"%b%y")
[1] NA
```

I tried escaping the latter format term with `\\` but same result--`NA`.
What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to include a day in your date. You can `paste()` in a day to get around this.

```
x <- paste0(1, format(Sys.Date(), "%b%y"))
as.Date(x, "%d%b%y")
```